# Access Win32 dll on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, winapi, google-app-engine, licensing

**BACKGROUND:**

I work on a small team in a large company where I'm currently revamping the licensing system for a suite of mixed .Net and Win32 products that I update annually. Each product references a win32 .dll for product validation. I only have the binary file and the header file for the licensing module (so no hash algorithm). Somehow customers are able to purchase software on our website and receive a disk in the mail with a serial key. Keys or product specific and so disks and keys can be easily shared.

**GOALS:**

- Modify the hash input so keys are now based on major version number (done).
- Implement a web service using App Engine (it's just me so I don't want to maintain any hardware) whereby a user can purchase a serial that is automatically generated and delivered via email.
- Use the existing licensing module or replicate the hash/API (I would like whoever is sending out serial keys to continue to do so except for maybe a minor change to their work flow, like adding the version number).

**QUESTIONS:**

- Is there any way to write wrap this win32 library in a python module and use it on Google's App Engine?
- Are there any tools to discover the hashing algorithm being used? The library exports a `generatekey` function?

Any other comments or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Tom

Comment: A disk in the mail? How quaint.

Comment: To answer your second question, your best bet is to decompile the DLL and examine the code to try and determine the algorithm. Even getting a list of symbols may give you some hints, based on what the functions are called.

Comment: Sorry, my second questions was malformed. I have the header file so I know the external symbols. My question is whether anyone knows of an application that can determine an algorithm using its inputs and outputs, i.e. INPUT: 2 4 6 + KEY: 12 => HASH: x1 + x2 + x3. I guess I'm envisioning a cubic fit to the data or something, which may not be possible depending on the strength of the algorithm, or worth the effort.

Comment: No - hash functions are arbitrarily complicated, and their output is designed to look random. Which is why more analysis and trial and error is more or less your only option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, App Engine's python runtime only supports pure python modules.  Wrapped native code modules won't work.

Comment: If you wanna run on a cloud provider, you can look into Azure.

Comment: Thanks, I've started the 90 day Azure trial and it looks like a good way to push native win32 binary to the cloud.